# How do I get the entire error stack when raising an exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code, which is meant to display a report of the state of the app when an error is encountered.

```
begin
    ... # makes calls to lower level instances
rescue
    send_report
end

def send_report
  str = ""
  str.concat("#{$!}\n\r")
  str.concat("Report ----------\n\r")
  ...
  raise str
end
```

The problem is that $! is only giving me a one line error without any of the usual stack trace.  An example error is:

```
DEBUG - undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

And this is shown without a file name or line number or any context.  How do I get that added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the variable to store the exception in (although you're right that they do get stored in `$!`, I prefer explicit non-global variables).

```
begin 
  # exception is raised
rescue Exception => e
  str = "#{e.message}\n"
  str << e.backtrace.join("\n")
  raise str
end
```

The reason you're only getting the error is that the exception being interpolated probably calls `to_s` on the Exception object, which [returns its message and not its backtrace.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html#method-i-to_s)

Comment: Better to use `raise e` or `raise` if you're trying to rethrow the same exception.

Comment: Actually, I was just copying what was in the original question without thinking about what the code was doing - just getting his code to do what he wanted. But you're right!

Comment: I like this better though, because I culled the call stack to only be 15 lines long.  Works great!  Thanks!

Comment: @JeremySmith Culling the call stack is generally a problem. You usually want to see exactly where things went wrong.